# Reduce an array to an 2D array with matching properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filtering

If I have one array of objects with inner properties like so:

```
var array = [
    {
        "Structure_SortID": "001.001.003",
    },
    {
        "Structure_SortID": "001.001.003",
    },
    {
        "Structure_SortID": "001.001.003",
    },
    {
        "Structure_SortID": "001.001.003",
    },
    {
        "Structure_SortID": "001.004.002",
    },
    {
        "Structure_SortID": "001.004.002",
    }
];
```

How can I reduce this one array into a single 2D array that contains 2 arrays of matching "Structure_SortID" properties?
Output should be:

```
var array = [
    // Filtered so only 001.004.002
    [
        {
            "Structure_SortID": "001.001.003",
        },
        {
            "Structure_SortID": "001.001.003",
        },
        {
            "Structure_SortID": "001.001.003",
        },
        {
            "Structure_SortID": "001.001.003",
        }
    ],
    // Filtered so only 001.004.002
    [
        {
            "Structure_SortID": "001.004.002",
        },
        {
            "Structure_SortID": "001.004.002",
        }
    ]
];
```

The solution needs to allow for an infinite number of lists with matching "Structre_SortID" properties. And needs to support situations where there is only 1 array of matching ID's inside the 2D array. And needs to support empty arrays or single item arrays alongside matching lists inside the 2D array.

Comment: I think the best option would be to add a key to each array and then remove it if you dont needed any more. 
```var array = [
   '001.004.003':
    {
        {
            "Structure_SortID": "001.001.003",
        },
        ....
        {
            "Structure_SortID": "001.001.003",
        }
    },
    '001.004.002':
    {
        {
            "Structure_SortID": "001.004.002",
        },
        {
            "Structure_SortID": "001.004.002",
        }
    }
];```
and then do another for loop and make the object an array as your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getArrayOfObjectByKey(data, key) {
    return Object.values(
        (data || []).reduce((acc, e) => {
            if (key in e) {
                let value = e[key];
                if (value in acc) {
                    acc[value].push(e);
                } else {
                    acc[value] = [e];
                }
            }
            return acc;
        }, {})
    );
}

var array = [
    {"Structure_SortID": "001.001.003"},
    {"Structure_SortID": "001.001.003"},
    {"Structure_SortID": "001.001.003"},
    {"Structure_SortID": "001.001.003"},
    {"Structure_SortID": "001.004.002"},
    {"Structure_SortID": "001.004.002"},
];
console.log(getArrayOfObjectByKey(array, 'Structure_SortID'));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much. The duplicate question that is apparently the same as my question, did NOT work for me. So thanks for answering regardless.